# ClickListener on a Spinner error

Tags: android, spinner, onclicklistener

I want to get if a Spinner has been clicked, I'm not interested in what item is selected, only if the user has clicked on the Spinner. When I try it, a compiler error is thrown that shows "Don't call setOnClickListener on a AdapterView...". I know that I've to use an OnItemClickListener, but in this case I want only to catch the click, not the information.
I use the same listener in several views for the same process.

Comment: plz post your code and the error you see in logcat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following code, it may be help you..

Instead of setting the spinner's `OnClickListener`,try setting `OnTouchListener` and `OnKeyListener`.

```
spinner.setOnTouchListener(spinnerOnTouch);
spinner.setOnKeyListener(spinnerOnKey);
and the listeners:

private View.OnTouchListener spinnerOnTouch = new View.OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            //Your code
        }
        return false;
    }
};
private static View.OnKeyListener spinnerOnKey = new View.OnKeyListener() {
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER) {
            //your code
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the following options:

1) Create a class `MySpinner` that extends `Spinner` and override its `onTouchEvent` method. There you can catch if the user has clicked the `Spinner`.

2) Actually set `OnItemClickListener`. Basically this listener will be fired any time the `Spinner` is clicked as it is fired each time an item is clicked and the `Spinner` itself is nothing but all the items.

Answer (score 0):

Your Activity must extend OnItemSelectedListener.
Then, you acitivty must implement 2 functions

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
        long arg3) {


}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

Don't forget to add listener on your spinner like this

```
yourspinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```